# i don't understand modus ponens

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I'm learning about modus ponens in propositional logic but it doesn't makes sense to me

I can think of an examples where a true premises leads to a false
conclusion:

p -> q

p

Therefore q

If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him
the kid is wet in the winter
Conclusion: it was raining on him

Where in fact:

• the kid is wet in the winter
• a passing car splashed water on him

Therefore
it is not the case it was raining on him.

Another example:
If the kid is smiling then he is happy
the kid is smiling therefore he is happy
(No,the kid just faked the smile it doesn't necessarily fellows that he is happy)

It's the same as saying:
if it have 4 legs then it is a dog,
it have 4 legs,therefore it is a dog.
(no it's a cat)

Meaning:
Q is just a possible outcome
and there is not enuff information
for us to deduce q as the true cause or the conclusion by applying modus ponens in natural language.
For modus ponens to be correct according
To its form, we need to see it as a necessary connection like the connection between fire and heat.

But as the examples shows
And as far as i know modus ponens is not considered as a necessary connection,
Rather it's considered as implication.
p imply q or if p then q
(some kind of a weak connection but not a necessary one).

Comment: "If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him" In your example this premise is false, since the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. But if all your premises *were* true, the conclusion would have to be true as well, that's all it means for an argument to be logically valid (on the other hand, a "sound" argument is logically valid *and* it has true premises, so your example is logically valid but unsound).

Comment: As many have already said ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181267/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181943/), **your conditional hypothesis is *not true* in the situations you describe** so modus ponens can't be applied there. I don't know what else you expect to hear at this point. "P->Q" means *exactly* that as soon as you know that P is true, you can immediately be absolutely certain that Q is true. This isn't the case in your "examples." Maybe you're mixing up necessary and sufficient conditions (e.g. it is true that "If the kid gets rained on then he is wet")?

Comment: @Hypnosifl thanks for your comment i think i understand what you are saying, but i don't see how this inference rule can help us in the real world rather then emphasizing the obvious.. if i walk on the street in winter outside, and i see a wet kid, and i have a general assumption(a Premise) that if the kid is wet then it was raining on him, how can i conclude correctly the cause?

Comment: If i can't what's the point of modus ponens except stating the obvious.

Comment: Real world inferences usually involve [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) which is fundamentally different than purely [deductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning), and formal logic (including modus ponens) is just about deductive reasoning. The most common application of pure deductive reasoning is probably in mathematical proofs; it may help to think of logic problems as basically like word-problems in math.

Comment: @Dasem, logic is in a sense stating the obvious. With one step the utility of it is not so clear, but with many more steps like in a mathematical proof it becomes very useful.

Comment: @Hypnosifl yeh, i don't see this inference rule making much sense outside the math world as i see it it pretty useless inference rule, any way thanks for your comment answer it formally and i will except it as an answer.

Comment: @Ameet ok thanks.

Comment: Propositional logic, not pre-, from proposition.

Comment: No “connection” only Truth. If “if p, then q” is true and p is true, then q is true also.

Comment: @Allegranza i will correct it my keyboard suggested it and i tought it was correct. (Not native english speaker)

Comment: @Hypnosifl the first comment as far as I'm concern is a good answer, use it and i will except it as an answer.

Comment: "what's the point of modus ponens except stating the obvious" First of all, the logical rules are *supposed* to be obvious: the idea is that we're trying to isolate a collection of rules which are individually obvious, but can be combined to prove non-obvious things. Second, and more subtly, you can also think of the logical rules as *definitions* of the connectives they involve. For example, implication is exactly the thing that behaves according to MP (and the other implication rules), so we shouldn't think of these as rules so much as definitions; if you're interested see "logical harmony."

Comment: Modus ponens is invalid inference rule outside the math and science world. It's ilogical inference rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him" In your example this premise is false, since the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. But if all your premises were true, the conclusion would have to be true as well, that's all it means for an argument to be logically valid (on the other hand, a "sound" argument is logically valid and it has true premises, so your example is logically valid but unsound).

Real world inferences usually involve [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) which is fundamentally different than purely [deductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning), and formal logic (including modus ponens) is just about deductive reasoning. The most common application of pure deductive reasoning is probably in mathematical proofs; it may help to think of logic problems as basically like word-problems in math.